Print Bank Reconciliation Summary in PDF in X++ 2012
I'm trying to print a report in pdf by code using x++ 2012. The report is the Bank Reconciliation Summary. What I have done by now is this:
    #define.ParamCheckingDate       ('CheckingDate')
    #define.ParamSummary            ('ReconciliationSummary')
    #define.ParamClearedDetails     ('ClearedTransactionDetails')
    #define.ParamUnclearedDetails   ('UnClearedTransactionDetails')
        
    SrsReportRunController               controller = new BankReconciliationSummaryController();
    SRSPrintDestinationSettings          settings;
    BankReconciliationSummaryRdlContract rdlContract;
    
    controller.parmReportName("BankReconciliationSummary.Report");
    controller.parmExecutionMode(SysOperationExecutionMode::ScheduledBatch);
    controller.parmShowDialog(false);
        
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamCheckingDate,mkDate(27,05,2024));
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamClearedDetails,true);
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamSummary,true);
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamUnclearedDetails,false);
        
    controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(rdlContract);
        
    settings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
    settings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::File);
    settings.fileFormat(SRSReportFileFormat::PDF);
    settings.fileName(@'C:\Users\spineda\Desktop\reporteTest.pdf');
        
    controller.startOperation();

The problem I'm facing right now is that the contract class is private and it doesn't let me set the values of the parms. There is already a way to print the report and I'm trying to replicate that by code. What I want is to set the parameters and the path by code. The process is:
1.I click the print button
2.I fill the parameters and click the Ok button
UPDATE
I found a way to set the values of the parms and now I'm creating the pdf file. The issue that I have now is that I don't want to show the dialog that confirms the params because I'm already setting them by code. Is there a way to set the dialog's visibility off? This is my code:
void clicked()
{
    #define.ParamCheckingDate       ('CheckingDate')
    #define.ParamSummary            ('ReconciliationSummary')
    #define.ParamClearedDetails     ('ClearedTransactionDetails')
    #define.ParamUnclearedDetails   ('UnClearedTransactionDetails')

    SrsReportRunController               controller = new BankReconciliationSummaryController();
    SRSPrintDestinationSettings          settings;
    SRSReportParameter checkingDateParam = new SRSReportParameter();
    SRSReportParameter clearedTransactionDetailsParam = new SRSReportParameter();
    SRSReportParameter reconciliationSummaryParam = new SRSReportParameter();
    SRSReportParameter unClearedTransactionDetailsParam = new SRSReportParameter();
    SrsReportRdlDataContract rdlContract;

    Map reportParametersMap = new Map(Types::String, Types::Class);
    Map rdlReportParamMap;

    checkingDateParam.name(#ParamCheckingDate);
    checkingDateParam.dataType("DateTime");

    clearedTransactionDetailsParam.name(#ParamClearedDetails);
    clearedTransactionDetailsParam.dataType("Boolean");

    reconciliationSummaryParam.name(#ParamSummary);
    reconciliationSummaryParam.dataType("Boolean");

    unClearedTransactionDetailsParam.name(#ParamUnclearedDetails);
    unClearedTransactionDetailsParam.dataType("Boolean");

    reportParametersMap.insert("CheckingDate", checkingDateParam);
    reportParametersMap.insert("ClearedTransactionDetails", clearedTransactionDetailsParam);
    reportParametersMap.insert("ReconciliationSummary", reconciliationSummaryParam);
    reportParametersMap.insert("UnClearedTransactionDetails", unClearedTransactionDetailsParam);

    rdlReportParamMap = SrsReportRunUtil::createClonedParameters(reportParametersMap);

    rdlContract = SrsReportRdlDataContract::newContract("BankReconciliationSummaryRdlContract", rdlReportParamMap);

    controller.parmReportName("BankReconciliationSummary.Report");
    controller.parmExecutionMode(SysOperationExecutionMode::Synchronous);
    controller.parmShowDialog(false);

    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamCheckingDate,DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(mkDate(27,05,2024), 0));
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamClearedDetails,true);
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamSummary,true);
    rdlContract.setValue(#ParamUnclearedDetails,false);

    controller.parmReportContract().parmRdlContract().setValue(#ParamCheckingDate,DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(mkDate(27,05,2024), 0));
    controller.parmReportContract().parmRdlContract().setValue(#ParamClearedDetails,true);
    controller.parmReportContract().parmRdlContract().setValue(#ParamSummary,true);
    controller.parmReportContract().parmRdlContract().setValue(#ParamUnclearedDetails,false);

    settings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
    settings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::File);
    settings.fileFormat(SRSReportFileFormat::PDF);
    settings.fileName(@'C:\Users\spineda\Desktop\reporteTestExitoso.pdf');

    controller.startOperation();
}


Why can't you set the values? The code below works for me -
rdlContract = controller.getDataContractObject(); // Add this line

rdlContract.setValue(#ParamCheckingDate, myDateTime);
rdlContract.setValue(#ParamClearedDetails,true);
rdlContract.setValue(#ParamSummary,true);
rdlContract.setValue(#ParamUnclearedDetails,false);

// controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(rdlContract); // Comment out

Oddly enough though, I had to tweak \C\BankReconciliationSummaryUIBuilder\getParameterSavedValues because of an issue with how date/utcDateTime were getting stored/converted.

Hi Alex, actually I found a way to set the values. I edited the post. Now, the only detail I'm facing is that I want to hide the dialog or set some visibility property of the dialog to false.

Have you tried controller.run() instead of .startOperation()?

Or controller.parmLoadFromSysLastValue(false);

It worked!! I used .run() instead of .startOperation() and it worked fine! The only thing is that, I don't know why, it takes too much time to save it (it shows a message that said that the file is in line) and when I use the normal print button it takes less time.

I fixed it! I had the value of parmExecutionMode set as ScheduledBatch instead of Synchronous. Thank you for your help!

Glad I could help!
